# Determine the dimensions of $W_1$ and $W_2$ and find basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

> $W_1$ ={$ax^4 +bx^3 +ax^2 +cx ∈P_4(\mathbb R)|a,b,c∈ (\mathbb R)$}
>
> $W_2$ ={$0x^4 +ax^3 −ax^2 +2bx+a∈P4((\mathbb R))|a,b∈(\mathbb R)$}

The question asks me to determine the dimensions and find bases.

$dim(W_1) = 3$ and $dim(W_2) = 2$ but how about the bases?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$ax^4+bx^3+ax^2+cx=a(x^4+x^2)+b(x^3)+c(x)$$

Comment: $(1,0,1,0), (0,1,0,0), (0,0,0,1) $ ??

Comment: $\{x^4+x^2, x^3, x\}$ for $W_1$.

Answer (score 1):

**hint for $W_2$**

$$W_2=\{a (x^3-x^2+1)+Bx, \;(a,B)\in\mathbb R^2\} $$

the two vectors $$P=x^3-x^2+1$$ and
$$Q=x $$ are independant, thus $(P,Q) $ is a base of $W_2$ and dim $W_2=2$.